# Flexbox: scrolling flexchild between two other flexchildren on content overflow

Tags: css, flexbox

i have a modal dialog, which is centered on an overlay.

The dialog is a flex container with three flex children and has a max-height of 90%.

if the height of the document is smaller then the needed height of the modal i want the second child(modal-body) to enable scrolling.

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-header"><h2>Modal Header</h2></div>
    <div class="modal-body">  <!--this should scroll if modal-height > 90% -->
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-controls"><!-- controls --></div>
</div>
```

i have no clue if that is possible with pure css.

```
.modal {
    position: relative;
    width: 10em;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.modal-header { flex: 1 auto; } 
.modal-body {
    flex: 1 auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}   
.modal-controls { flex: 1 auto; }
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWvKB/) of my approach.

If you resize the output window you can see that the modal dialog gets cut at the bottom instead of scroll the overflow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. All you need is to replace

```
.modal {
    ...
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

with

```
.modal {
    ...
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

And it works. Not required, but you should also prevent the modal-header and modal-controls to expand:

```
.modal-header, .modal-controls {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.modal {
    ...
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/omulet/qoabrp9c/)